# GhostScript 9.20 - successor to -dUseCIEColor?

Tags: ghostscript

I'm using a script to batch convert scanned PDF 1.4 (or before) to PDF/A-1b. The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.pdf; do gs -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dUseCIEColor -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFACompatibilityLevel=1 -sOutputFile=output/$i $i;

done
```

This script works fine and the converted PDF/A-1b files validates when trying their conformance with veraPDF 1.8.3.

However there is a warning message that the flag **-dUseCIEColor** is obsolete and should not be used more since GhostScript 9.12.

Then I remove **-dUseCIEColor** from my script and the warning message is gone. Unfortunately my PDF/A-1b files cease to validate when doing so? Any ideas?

I read that the successor to **-dUseCIEColor** should be **dColorConversionStrategy=RGB** (or CMYK), but I've tried to implement it in the script but it doesn't work.

What would be the correct approach in todays version of GhostScript?

Many thanks in advance.

/Paul

Comment: Could you find a fix for this?

Comment: I think the problem disappeared in version 9.22.

Comment: Very similar question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44278100/pdf-to-pdf-a-2b-without-duseciecolor

Answer (score 0):

Using `DeviceRGB` or `DeviceCMYK` colors with the following conversion:

```
-sColorConversionStrategy=UseDeviceIndependentColor
```

seems to solve the problem for me. `UseCIEColor` is no longer needed.